# Three.js Camera Rotation using axis angle method

Tags: three.js

I am trying to write a control that will allow the user to rotate an object my using left/right arrows to rotate around the X axis and up/down arrows to rotate around the Y axis. (I understand that the objects internal coordinate system will not match the world coordinate system once I start rotating).

I can rotate my object around the Y axis as follows:

```
    var axis = new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0);
    aMatrix.makeRotationAxis( axis.normalize(), incr );
    obj.rotation.setFromRotationMatrix( aMatrix );
```

where incr is the amount to rotate.

And I can rotate my object around the X axis as follows:

```
    var axis = new THREE.Vector3(1,0,0);
    aMatrix.makeRotationAxis( axis.normalize(), incr );
    obj.rotation.setFromRotationMatrix( aMatrix );
```

Both work fine. However when I go from one to the other (rotate X, then rotate Y), the other axis snaps back to the zero position. So if I rotate around X, 45 degrees, then start to rotate around Y, my X rotation goes back to zero.

I am setting:

```
        obj.useQuaternion = true;
```

in all cases.

What am I doing wrong?

r69

Comment: (1) What are you trying to do? (2) What revision of three.js are you using? (3) Try `object.rotateY( radians )`.

Comment: Updated the questions for (1) and (2). I did try rotateY, rotateX, but (a) I get gimbal lock, and (b) the interaction with euler order is unclear to me. I'm trying to draw the axes of rotation and with quaternions the axes make sense (a Y rotation rotates around the Y axis, an X rotation rotates around the X axis, but with euler rotations I'm not getting that result.

Comment: (1) `useQuaternion` is not a property of `Object3D`. (2) I can answer questions about the current revision of three.js only. I would suggest you update, anyway. (3) Are you trying to rotate around THE Y-axis and THE X-axis -- or the objects internal axes?

Comment: (2) ok, i'll upgrade. (3) I'm trying to rotate around the object's internal axes. Imagine a spaceship where left/right keys rotate the ship around the ship's internal X axis by firing thrusters, etc. (not actually what I'm doing but a good enuf model).

Comment: My suggestion in my first comment should work. Or try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28569026/three-js-extract-rotation-in-radians-from-camera/28569296#28569296

Comment: @West. I have a jfiddle using the latest version of three.js and using the rotation method you recommend: http://jsfiddle.net/blwoodley/r4wzk2mt/ . I am drawing the rotation axes on the screen as you'll see.  I press left/right arrow and my mesh rotates around the red axis. Then I press up/down arrow and it rotates around the green axis. All as expected. But then if I go back and hold down left arrow, the mesh wobbles and doesn't seem to rotate around its internal axes, at least as I conceive them. Thanks for your patience and help.

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/r4wzk2mt/1/.

Answer (score 0):

Rotation matrices created using Matrix.makeRotationAxis only store rotation around that axis. To rotate around two axes, you need to create two matrices (one for each axis) and multiply those.

so:

```
matrixXY = new THREE.Matrix4();

matrixX.makeRotationAxis(axisX, angleX);
matrixY.makeRotationAxis(axisY, angleY);
matrixXY.multiplyMatrices(matrixX, matrixY);

obj.rotation.setFromRotationMatrix(matrixXY);
```

There are a lot of options when working with rotation, so there may be an easier way for your use case.